# How to retain dynamically created table after window reload

Tags: javascript, html

My code to create dynamic table on click  of a button

`-Createlist()` is called on **"create table" button-adds** table row on each click

`-Deletelist()` is called on **"remove table" button-deletes** row

```
var flag =0;
function createlist(){
    var info = {};
    info.name = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
    info.gender = document.forms["myform"]["gender"].value;
    info.age = document.forms["myform"]["age"].value;
    var header;
    var node = [];
    node[0] = document.createTextNode('Name');
    node[1] = document.createTextNode('Gender');
    node[2] = document.createTextNode('Age');

    if(flag==0){
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            var header = document.createElement('TH');
            header.setAttribute('class','header');
            header.appendChild(node[i]);
            document.getElementById('list').appendChild(header);
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for(var key in info){
        if (info.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            td.textContent = info[key];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: This is usually done by sending the changes to the server using AJAX, and saving them in a database. When you reload the page, it gets the information from the database and shows the updated table.

Comment: I want to save it in localstorage somehow because I am working in frontend only. Can you help in this?

Comment: That seems like a poor design. It means they have to use the same computer to access the saved information. But it sounds like you know how to do it, so what's your question?

Comment: Ya it is a bad design , but I am trying on a pet project.Can you give one example code line to save one table row in localstorage?

Comment: Don't save just one table row. Put all the table data into an array of objects. Convert it to JSON and then save it in `localStorage`. When reloading the page, get the item from `localStorage`, use `JSON.parse()` to convert it back to an array, and build the table from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really a fan of this approach. I would advise to use a database for this, and get the data at each page loads. If someone builds a massive table, then these information are being stored in the browser's localStorage...

But if you insist on it, here below is an example of how I've implemented it. **Please note that this doesn't work on SO** due of security reasons. For a live working example, please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13yzhL02/). Ensure that you are using concise namings. The `mytable` example that I have used is not a good example because another dev can override this if he uses that too.

```js
// this one reads the table and adds it to the storage
function addToStorage() {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#t tbody tr');
  const col1 = []; // each column will have their own array. Please name them accordingly
  const col2 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    const tds = rows[i].children;
    col1.push(tds[0].textContent);
    col2.push(tds[1].textContent);
  }
  // "mytable" is just an example. PLEASE PICK A GOOD AND CONCISE NAME !
  window.localStorage.setItem('mytable', JSON.stringify({
    col1: col1,
    col2: col2
  })); 
}

// this one cleans the table (to show PoC)
function clearTable() {
  const t = document.querySelector('#t tbody');
  t.innerHTML = '';
}

// duh
function makeTd(txtContent) {
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = txtContent;
    return td;
}

// this one gets the info from storage and displays the table content if present
function getFromStorage() {
  const infoFromStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('mytable');
  if (infoFromStorage) {
      const json = JSON.parse(infoFromStorage);
      const tbody = document.querySelector('#t tbody');
      for(let i = 0; i < json.col1.length; ++i) {
          const tr = document.createElement('tr');
          tr.appendChild(makeTd(json.col1[i])); // note, column names must match with that one in addToStorage
          tr.appendChild(makeTd(json.col2[i]));
          tbody.appendChild(tr);
      }
  }
  else {
    console.log('not present in storage. Find a tactic to handle this');
  }
}



document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', addToStorage);
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clearTable);
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', getFromStorage);
```

```html
<button id="add">Add to storage</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
<button id="get">Get from storage</button>
<table id="t">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo_1</td>
      <td>foo_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bar_1</td>
      <td>bar_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways. First of all you can save your data in server while creating the tables and fetch them once the page reloads. Or you can use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for storing stuffs.]

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
   //if not support storage I think you can append the data to the url, and parse the url after page reload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 localstorage to save the table data temporary and read it back on page refresh.

Comment: Can you give one exaple code line to save one row of the table?

Comment: why not store the entire html of the table in localStorage using innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can make use  **localStorage.setItem()**

```
localStorage.setItem(name,"harsh");
localStorage.setItem(gender,"male");
localStorage.setItem(age,"24");
```